# facing some issues in loading application from server to blackberry mobile

Tags: blackberry-eclipse-plugin

am trying to access data from the server .. but am getting an error.

```
HTTP Error 500:internal Server Error
```

> An Unexpected condition was encountered which prevented your request
>   from being fulfilled this could be caused by a problem with the
>   gateway,a server,or a problem with the page itself. please try
>   reloading a different page ...

This is the problem am facing .. please help me.

Comment: your request may be fail server authentication i think this is security issue

Comment: then how to access my application in the server .. please tel me the alternative

Comment: can i see your url if it is not secret?

Comment: String url="http://59.90.131.72:8084/SFTS/leaveDetails.jsp?empid=12303;deviceside=true";
     HttpConnection conn = (HttpConnection) Connector.open(url, Connector.READ_WRITE);
     conn.setRequestMethod(HttpConnection.GET);
     InputStream data = conn.openInputStream();

Answer (score 0):

This error is usually caused when people are on a BES (as opposed to BIS).
The BES needs to be reconfigured to allow the Proxy to allow you access.
The MDS needs to have configuration changes.

Comment: actually i have changer the blackberry mobiles version from 4.6.1.3 to 5.0.0 . when i access the application its showing the above error .. when i am using the original 5.0.0 version its everything working ..